# Combining Date Range and Like SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I am getting the error: ORA-01861: literal does not match format string

I was trying to create a select statement where I can find a the entity_id and name before march 3rd of 2013 and have a status report = W.

```
SELECT ENTITY_ID,NAME FROM STATUS_TABLE
WHERE DATERETURN <= '2013-03-01'
AND REPORT_STATUS LIKE 'W';
```

Comment: Don't forget to specify the database engine in your question tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change this:

```
WHERE DATERETURN <= '2013-03-01'
```

to this:

```
WHERE DATERETURN <= to_date('2013-03-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd')
```

Answer (score 2):

Oracle wont understand literal date format strings. You should to use the TO_DATE function:

```
WHERE DATERETURN <= TO_DATE('2013-03-01 00:00:00')
```

or the ANSI syntax

```
WHERE DATERETURN <= DATE'2014-02-05'
```